# python can't start because api-ms-win-crt-runtime-I1-1-0.dll is missing

Tags: python-3.x

I just installed python 3 on my desktop ... when I try to run it, I get the message:

> "The program can't start because api-ms-win-crt-runtime-I1-1-0.dll is missing from your computer.

I've installed it three times now, and the same thing happens every time.

Comment: You probably need to add it to the PATH, or you're putting it in the wrong folder.

Comment: That’s no Python problem. Your Windows is broken.

[Download Windows Update](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2999226)

Comment: [ Thanks.. That actually solves.. ] \(^_^)>